# How to use reduceByKey a row in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

**I have a data set like**:
[A,(1,2)],[B,(3,4)],[A,(5,6)]

**How to get an output** 
[A,(1,2),(5,6)],[B,(3,4)]

*using Pyspark*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are grouping and you are not applying functions, I think you need to use **groupByKey()**

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([["A",(1,2)],["B",(3,4)],["A",(5,6)]])
>>> print rdd.take(3)
[['A', (1, 2)], ['B', (3, 4)], ['A', (5, 6)]]

>>> rdd_group = rdd.groupByKey()
>>> print rdd_group.take(3)
[('A', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f5f53fa1c90>), ('B', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x7f5f53fa1790>)]

>>> rdd_output = rdd_group.mapValues(list)
>>> print rdd_output.take(3)
[('A', [(1, 2), (5, 6)]), ('B', [(3, 4)])]
```